# Memory efficient computation of md5sum of a file in vlang

Tags: file, md5sum, vlang

The following code read a file into bytes and computes the md5sum of the bytes array. It works but I would like to find a solution in V that need less RAM.
Thanks for your comments !

```
import os
import crypto.md5

b := os.read_bytes("file.txt") or {panic(err)}

s := md5.sum(b).hex()

println(s)
```

I also tried without success :

```
import os
import crypto.md5
import io

mut f := os.open_file("file.txt", "r")?

mut h := md5.new()

io.cp(mut f, mut h)?

s := h.sum().hex()

println(s) // does not return the correct md5sum
```

Comment: I don't know vlang, but MD5 only needs 512 bits, I'm having a bit of a hard time seeing how you could implement it in a non-memory-efficient manner!

Comment: I think reading the file into bytes is not memory efficient. I did not find a better way in V.

Comment: that makes no sense. File-IO is bytes based, that's how files work, and 512 bits is perfectly divisible by bytes, so it's really not clear why this would be memory-inefficient. Can you explain why you think so?

Comment: Note that I *really* don't know V, and it seems to be a bit of an "esoteric" language, seeing I can't find a wikipedia article on it? Does `os.read_bytes("filename")` already actually read all the file into a buffer, or does it construct a reader which `md5.sum()` can then use to iterate through the file contents?

Comment: according to the documentation (https://modules.vlang.io/os.html#read_bytes)  read_bytes() returns all bytes read from file.

Comment: Hah! I know this sounds stupid, but this is progress: ah, so, then don't use that `read_bytes`. What kind of parameters does `md5.sum` accept?

Comment: unfortunately I did not find a better solution that I managed to make working with the help of the documentation (https://modules.vlang.io/crypto.md5.html). This is why I ask a better solution here :)

Comment: hm again, I don't know V, and I can only guess `[]u8` means "a buffer of bytes", and not "something that behaves like a sequence of bytes, e.g. a buffer, or a file reader". If that is true, these standard functions are pretty useless for efficient implementations, indeed (hashes are *very* commonly calculated for large data structures. Word of warning: Md5 is very insecure in that it's easy to find different data that has the same md5 hash as the actual data). In that case, you'd have to implement a better library yourself! Not a big deal, as it seems V at least gives you byte-level access.

Comment: (Sorry to hear I was wrong, and sorry your library isn't better! But that's a chance you can become a hero: by writing better libraries. I don't know how the formal process is for standardizing what is in the V standard library, so other developers can use it, but maybe you could contribute your improved `crypto` module back upstream!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty. This is what you're looking for. It produces the same result as `md5sum` and is only slightly slower. `block_size` is inversely related to the amount of memory used and speed at which the checksum is computed. Decreasing `block_size` will lower the memory footprint, but takes longer to compute. Increasing `block_size` has the opposite effect. I tested on a 2GB manjaro disc image and can confirm the memory usage is very low.

Note: It seems this does perform noticeably slower without the `-prod` flag. The V compiler makes special optimizations in order to run faster for the production build.

```
import crypto.md5
import io
import os

fn main() {
    println(hash_file('manjaro.img')?)
}

const block_size = 64 * 65535

fn hash_file(path string) ?string {
    mut file := os.open(path)?
    defer {
        file.close()
    }
    mut buf := []u8{len: block_size}
    mut r := io.new_buffered_reader(reader: file)
    mut digest := md5.new()
    for {
        x := r.read(mut buf) or { break }
        digest.write(buf[..x])?
    }
    return digest.checksum().hex()
}
```

Comment: interesting solution !  Could you explain why "65535" ? Thanks !

Comment: No, reason for that number specifically. It's just the biggest power of two I knew off the top of my head. But, like I said, a bigger number will be faster at the expense of using more memory. `64 * 65535` is how many bytes from the file will be loaded into memory (4.19 MB).

Comment: Theoretically, this should be able to be increase to the size of the file in bytes. But V requires `int` to be used when indexing arrays, so someone would have to make a custom md5 module that uses `map[u64]u8` in place of `[]u8` arrays for that to work.

Answer (score -1):

To conclude what I've learned from the comments:

- V is a programming language with typed arguments
- `md5.sum` takes a byte array argument, and not something that is a sequence of bytes, e.g. read from a file as-you-go.
- There's no alternative to `md5.sum`

So, you will have to implement MD5 yourself. Maybe the standard library is open source and you can build upon that! Or, you can just bind any of the existing (e.g. C) implementations of MD5 and feed in bytes as you read them, in chunks of 512 bits = 2⁶ Bytes.

**EDIT**: I don't know V, so it's hard for me to judge, but it would look [`Digest.write`](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/master/vlib/crypto/md5/md5.v#L55) would be a method to consecutively push data through the MD5 calculation. Maybe that together with a while loop reading bytes from the file is the solution?

Comment: Along with `Digest.write` you can use `File.read_bytes` if that helps. https://modules.vlang.io/os.html#File.read_bytes

Comment: I would think this would be more memory efficient since there's only 64 bytes being read at a time, but it consumes even more memory than just hashing the whole file at once.
https://pastebin.com/bcvd6q98
Edit: It also doesn't produce the same result as hashing the whole file which is a problem. But since it relies on the previous hash to perform the next hash. It has the same effect where changing one character in the file will change the hash.

Comment: not sure what `hash +=...` does, but that's not what you need to do. You need to write these bytes through a `Digest` object.

Comment: `hash +=` is string concatenation. I probably should've commented it. But the code in the for loop concatenates the previous hash and the next 512 bits of the opened file. Then hashes it again.

Comment: @AdamOates thank so much you for providing code ! I tested it, but the md5sum it produces is not the same than the md5sum command line tool. So I cannot use this method to verify third party files :)

Comment: @AdamOates yep, guessed so, but that's not how a md5sum for a file larger than 512 bits is calculated!